# Storing a function call from one header inside another header

Tags: c

```
#include "alotMonster.h"
#include "troll.h"

// alotMonster has a function named createAlotMonster()
// troll has a function named createTroll()

int main (void) {
   createAlotMonster(createTroll()); 
}

  // The function createTroll() is then saved inside a variable within createAlotMonster for later use.
```

**How exactly can something like this be achieved in c?** So basically storing a function call from one header inside another header.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: Unclear question. You might want to use [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer). Be aware that C does not have *genuine* [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). Read about [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29). Please make the difference between functions and function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "function call" is not an object in C, i.e. it's not something you can store. A call is an action, it happens when a function is called. It's not something that has a size, i.e. it can't be stored.

You might want a function *pointer*, which is a way of referencing functions for calling later.

If we were to invent some prototypes, let's say

```
int createTroll(const char *name, int strength);
```

then you can reference that function using a pointer like this:

```
int (*troll_function)(const char *, int) = createTroll;
```

so you would have `createAlotMonster()` take such a pointer:

```
vod createAlotMonster(int (*monster_function)(const char *, int));
```

Then you can call it almost like you showed:

```
createAlotMonster(createTroll);
```

Note that there are no `()` after `createTroll`, we're *not* calling the function just passing its address to `createAlotMonster()`.

Also note that there is no "storing inside header", headers can't store data. They can't do anything, they are just source files with declarations. The code that implements `createAlotMonster()` must be adjusted in order to support taking a function pointer as an argument for this to work, you can't force it to do something it wasn't designed to do.